# How to make my application to read my file when selected and when the user selects a folder then making the application to read all the files in it?

Tags: java, swing

I am just trying to make a Java Swing application that reads a pattern from a file and scans or matches the patterns.... This is so far the ActionListener I have created but it won't read any folder's files. 
Can any one help on solving me this problem?

```
    public static class loadListener implements ActionListener{
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // ... Point the current directory.
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".//");
                fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                // ... Get the selected file
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                if (file != null) {
                    setFile(file);
                    setUserPromptLabel(file.getName());
                }
            }
    }

    public static void setFile(File file) {
        fileBytesArray = readFile(file);
    }

    public static void setUserPromptLabel(String infoTxt) {
        panel.userPromptLabel.setText(infoTxt);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Byte> readFile(File file) {
        ArrayList<Byte> fileBytes = new ArrayList<>();
        try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            int nextByte;
            byte currentByte;
            // ... loop and store the byte in fileBytes
            while ((nextByte = is.read()) != -1) {
                currentByte = (byte) nextByte;
                fileBytes.add(currentByte);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return fileBytes;
    }
```

This is my code to read the file. Can anybody help me out on this one ?

Comment: Apart from everything else: a `ArrayList<Byte>` is a **terribly** inefficient way to store bytes. It'll use **at least** 4x as much memory as a simple `byte[]` uses and that's assuming that you don't create new `Byte` objects and use 32 bit references, in reality it'll be much more.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Comment: Can you explain what is going wrong?  Do you see the dialog? How do you know the file isn't being read?

Answer (score 0):

Improvements

Don't read your files into an ArrayList of bytes just return an normal byte array

```
public static byte[] readFile(File file)
{
  try(FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file))
  {
    byte fullFile[]=new byte[file.length()];
    fis.read(fullFile);
    return fullFile;
  }
 /*return null or exit program incase of IO errors*/
}
```

Your answer

```
public static void setFile(File file)
{
 if(file.isDirectory())
 {
  Arrays.asList(file.listFiles())
             .forEach(child->
              {
               byte fileData[]=readFile(child);
               /* Do your pattern matching here or store this file in an 
seperate list*/
              });
 }
 else
 { 
  byte fileData[]=readFile(file);
  /* Your pattern matching here*/
 }
 }
```

Comment: What about `Files.readAllBytes` Also if you cannot handle an exception, just declare the method to throw the exception.

Comment: yes you can do that too but that method belongs to java 11 and i'm just trying to be backward compatible here

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html since java 1.7. What does your answer solve for the OP though? Sure it gets them a byte[] instead of a List<Byte>, but is that even an issue they're having?

Comment: well it was just an suggestion and the byte[] isn't the issue he is having. He just wanted to know how to read all files in an directory. Thanks for the doc suggestion didn't know that my bad

Answer (score 0):

1. Are the files big (eg over 2GB each) or small?
2. What encoding is used in files?
3. Is there a specific extention of file names to search?
4. Is the search pattern a simple string literal or a regular expression?
5. Can you parse line-by-line or the pattern includes new-line characters?
6. What do you want to do with the matching files? Return them all, return only the first occurence, or simply return a flag to indicate it was found?
7. What do you want to do with the non matching files?
8. Do you want to search directory/file path names themsevles?
9. Do you want to filter out non-text files or not?

I implemented a searching code which answers to the above questions like so:

1. Small.
2. UTF-8 by default, but can use any `Charset`.
3. Optionally specify included extentions or excluded ones from the search.
4. Can be either one.
5. You don't parse line-by-line. That makes the need of files to be small but gives possibility to search for patterns with new line characters.
6. Return a set containing all matched files.
7. Ignore them.
8. No. Only file contents. But you can use the same logic for path names (ie scan them as `String` objects with a `Scanner`).
9. Optionally (by specifying their extentions as in 3).

### The code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Searcher {

    public static class Builder {
        private String pattern;
        private int patternFlags;
        private Charset charset;
        private FileFilter filter;
        private Iterable<String> extentions;
        private boolean extentionsInclusives;
        private Locale caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale;
        private short maxDepth;

        public Builder() {
            pattern = null;
            patternFlags = 0;
            charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
            filter = null;
            extentions = Collections.emptyList();
            extentionsInclusives = false;
            caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale = Locale.getDefault();
            maxDepth = -1;
        }

        /**
         * Specifies the {@code Pattern} used to check against the files while searching. Here you
         * specify a regular expression instead of a literal {@code String} and also supply the
         * {@code Pattern} flags you want (according to {@link Pattern#compile(java.lang.String, int)}
         * method). The default value is not set.
         * @param regex
         * @param flags
         * @return 
         * @see #literal(java.lang.String)
         */
        public Builder regex(final String regex, final int flags) {
            pattern = regex;
            patternFlags = flags;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Specifies the {@code Pattern} used to check against the files while searching. Here you
         * specify a literal {@code String} to be used instead of a regular expression. The default
         * value is not set.
         * @param s
         * @return 
         * @see #regex(java.lang.String, int)
         */
        public Builder literal(final String s) {
            pattern = Pattern.quote(s);
            patternFlags = 0;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * The default value is {@link StandardCharsets#UTF_8}.
         * @param charset The {@code Charset} the files will be decoded with, in order to scan for the search pattern.
         * @return 
         */
        public Builder charset(final Charset charset) {
            this.charset = charset;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Specifies a {@code FileFilter} to be used when listing the files and subdirectories of a
         * directory (used only when the {@link #depth(short) depth} allows subdirectory searching,
         * ie is not equal to zero). Supply {@code null} in order to not use a particular filter.
         * The default value is {@code null}.
         * @param filter
         * @return 
         * @see #depth(short)
         */
        public Builder filter(final FileFilter filter) {
            this.filter = filter;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Specifies the file extentions of files to be checked. For example, if one wants to include
         * nothing but only files with {@code "txt"} extention, then should call this method with
         * the first argument to {@code true} and then the literal {@code "txt"}. Extentions are
         * always plain literal {@code String}s (without beginning with the dot character) and not
         * regular expressions. For another example, if one wants to exclude nothing but only files
         * with {@code "png"} and {@code "jpg"} extentions, then should call this method with the
         * first argument to {@code false} and then the literals {@code "png"} and {@code "jpg"}. If
         * one wants to include every file, no matter what extention it has, then he should call
         * this method with an empty array of extentions and {@code false} for the first argument
         * (something like <i>excluding the nothing</i>, ie <i>include everything</i>). The default
         * value is to include everything. Refer to {@link #extentionCaseInsenstivityLocale(java.util.Locale)}
         * to specify whether the extentions will be checked as case sensitive or not.
         * @param inclusives
         * @param extentions
         * @return 
         * @see #extentionCaseInsenstivityLocale(java.util.Locale)
         */
        public Builder extentions(final boolean inclusives, final String... extentions) {
            this.extentions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(extentions));
            extentionsInclusives = inclusives;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Specifies whether the extentions specified by {@link #extentions(boolean, java.lang.String...)}
         * are case sensitive or not. Use any non-null {@code Locale} to make them case insensitive.
         * Use {@code null} to make the extentions case sensitive. The default value is the
         * {@link Locale#getDefault() default Locale} (which means the extentions are case
         * insensitive by default).
         * @param locale
         * @return 
         * @see #extentions(boolean, java.lang.String...)
         */
        public Builder extentionCaseInsenstivityLocale(final Locale locale) {
            this.caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale = locale;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Specifies the <b>maximum</b> depth the recursion in subdirectories will take place while
         * searching for the pattern. Any negative value means there is not limit to the depth of
         * the recursion. A value of zero means that only the given file in
         * {@link Searcher#search(java.io.File) the search method} will be checked. A value of
         * {@code 1} means that the given path will be recursed once (if it is a directory), ie the
         * given path is a file so it will be scanned, or the given path is a directory in which
         * case the files inside it (and only) will be scanned.
         * @param d
         * @return 
         */
        public Builder depth(final short d) {
            maxDepth = d;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Builder's state is preserved.
         * @return the newly created {@code Searcher}.
         */
        public Searcher build() {
            Objects.requireNonNull(pattern, "Pattern is not set. You must call at least once the method 'regex(...)' or the method 'literal(...)'.");
            return new Searcher(Pattern.compile(pattern, patternFlags), charset, filter, extentions, extentionsInclusives, caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale, maxDepth);
        }
    }

    private static String getFilePathNameExtention(final String path) {
        final int dotI = path.lastIndexOf('.'),
                  sepI = path.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
        if (sepI < dotI)
            return path.substring(dotI + 1);
        return "";
    }

    private final Pattern pattern;
    private final FileFilter filter;
    private final String charset;
    private final Locale caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale;
    private final HashSet<String> extentions;
    private final short maxDepth;
    private final boolean extentionsInclusives;

    public Searcher(final Pattern pattern,
                    final Charset charset,
                    final FileFilter filter, //Can be null, to list everything.
                    final Iterable<String> extentions,
                    final boolean extentionsInclusives, //Indicates whether extentions are inclusives or exclusives.
                    final Locale caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale, //Can be null, for case sensitive extentions.
                    final short maxDepth) { //Negative for no max, zero for only current path, etc...
        this.pattern = Objects.requireNonNull(pattern);
        this.charset = charset.name();
        this.extentions = new HashSet<>();
        if (caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale != null)
            extentions.forEach(extention -> this.extentions.add(extention.toLowerCase(caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale)));
        else
            extentions.forEach(extention -> this.extentions.add(extention));
        this.extentionsInclusives = extentionsInclusives;
        this.filter = filter;
        this.caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale = caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale;
        this.maxDepth = maxDepth;
    }

    protected boolean isExtentionScanableContents(String extention) {
        if (caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale != null)
            extention = extention.toLowerCase(caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale);
        return !(extentionsInclusives ^ extentions.contains(extention)); //XNOR requires equal both sides.
    }

    protected boolean canScanContents(final File file) {
        return file.isFile() && isExtentionScanableContents(getFilePathNameExtention(file.toString()));
    }

    protected boolean canListContents(final File directory, final short currentDepth) {
        return directory.isDirectory() && (maxDepth < 0 || currentDepth < maxDepth);
    }

    protected void search(final File fileOrDirectory, final short currentDepth, final Collection<File> found) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (canListContents(fileOrDirectory, currentDepth))
            for (final File f: (filter == null? fileOrDirectory.listFiles(): fileOrDirectory.listFiles(filter)))
                search(f, (short) (currentDepth + 1), found);
        if (canScanContents(fileOrDirectory) && (null != new Scanner(fileOrDirectory, charset).findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0)))
            found.add(fileOrDirectory);
    }

    /**
     * Searches the contents of the files in the given path if the path is a directory, or scans the
     * contents of the given path itself if the path is a normal file. All search options are
     * specified at construction time.
     * @param fileOrDirectory
     * @return All the files/paths that contain in their contents the search pattern.
     * @throws FileNotFoundException If the file is successfully listed but then moved and unreachable before its scanning operation takes place.
     */
    public HashSet<File> search(final File fileOrDirectory) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final HashSet<File> found = new HashSet<>();
        search(fileOrDirectory, (short) 0, found);
        return found;
    }
}
```

### Searcher's (and Builder's) properties:

- **pattern**: the pattern to search. Specified by the methods `regex` and `literal` of the `Searcher.Builder` class (or a `Pattern` directly at the `Searcher`'s constructor).
- **charset**: the charset to use to decode the files. Default is UTF-8.
- **filter**: the filtering while listing files from directories. Default is `null` which translates to no filter (ie list everything).
- **extentions**: the extentions of the file names to include-to or exclude-from the search. The default is an empty set.
- **extentionsInclusives**: tells if the *extentions* are included-to or excluded-from the search. The default is to exclude (but with the empty set above, this makes to exclude nothing, ie include every file).
- **caseInsenstivityExtentionLocale**: the `Locale` to be used when comparing case insensitive file name extentions. The default is `Locale.getDefault` which makes them case insensitive for the user's `Locale`.
- **depth**: the maximum depth of directories to reach. Negative value for no limit, zero value for only the current given file, value of 1 for listing given directory's files and so on...

### How to use it?

You can simply copy paste it in a java file named *Searcher.java* and you are ready to go.

I embeded enough javadocs in the `Searcher.Builder` class's methods to give more details.

Here is a sample code on how to use it:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Searcher.Builder builder = new Searcher.Builder();

        final Searcher searcher =
            builder.literal("String to search")
                   .extentions(true, "txt", "java")
                   .build();

        final JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        jfc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
        if (JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION == jfc.showOpenDialog(null)) {
            final File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            if (selectedFile != null) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Only txt and java files: " + searcher.search(selectedFile));
                }
                catch (final FileNotFoundException fnfx) {
                    System.err.println("Error: " + fnfx);
                }
            }
            else
                System.err.println("null file.");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Cancelled.");
    }
}
```